# Pass each item in an array as a flag argument to a command in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to know how to pass each items in an array as an argument to a flag in a command.

For instance,

```
myCommand -f foo1 -f foo2, ... -f fooN
```

I would like to define an array such that

```
FOOS=("foo1" "foo2" ... "fooN")
```

and iterate over the array to use as `-f` flag in the example.

In my case, I would like to pass each file in a directory to some command, each using `-f` command. Any ideas?

Comment: Notice that you shouldn't use commas in the array declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most robust solution is to manually build a second list:

```
args=()
for foo in "${FOOS[@]}"; do args+=(-f "$foo"); done

myCommand "${args[@]}"
```

There's no really simple way to do it. You could use string substitution to prepend `"-f "` before each item. It'll work up until one of the arguments has whitespace or a glob and then it won't.

```
myCommand ${FOOS[@]/#/-f }
```

(Notice the *lack* of quoting around `${FOOS...}`.)

Answer (score 1):

If the command allows flags and their arguments to be directly attached (e.g. `myCommand -ffoo1 -ffoo2 ...`), you can do this directly by prepending `-f` to the array elements on expansion:

```
myCommand "${FOOS[@]/#/-f}"
```

...but of course, not all commands allow this. There's also a potential problem with empty (zero-length) arguments; they're indistinguishable from the argument being passed separately, so this trick will cause the following flag to be misparsed as the argument to the empty one.

Note that some commands allow long-form flags with `=` delimiting the argument (e.g. `myCommand -file=foo1 -file=foo2 ...`), in which case this will work and the problem with empty arguments shouldn't apply.